# Web Service XML to OLE DB: No Data being loaded

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

Running VS2015(SSDT) and SQL Server 2014. I'm new to SSIS/XML and I'm trying to consume a web service which lets me choose 2 methods in the Web Service Task: ExportDataset and ExportXML. I'm trying to write this data to a SQL Server table with an `ID` int column. The Web Service Task outputs to a file.

When I input the generated ExportDataSet xml into "XML Source" from file, I can use inline schema, select and map columns, and output to OLE DB database. But 0 rows are written when package executes.

When I input the generated ExportXML xml into "XML Source" from file, there's no schema and the "Generated XSD" option doesn't give any columns in the Mapping section so the package can't execute.

What am I missing? Which XML/XSD can I use?

**ExportDataset** generated code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="id" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <id>2</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
        <id>3133</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
        <id>3134</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
        <id>3135</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
        <id>3157</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table6" msdata:rowOrder="5">
        <id>3183</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table7" msdata:rowOrder="6">
        <id>3263</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table8" msdata:rowOrder="7">
        <id>3291</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table9" msdata:rowOrder="8">
        <id>3292</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table10" msdata:rowOrder="9">
        <id>3371</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="10">
        <id>3429</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table12" msdata:rowOrder="11">
        <id>3431</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table13" msdata:rowOrder="12">
        <id>3439</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table14" msdata:rowOrder="13">
        <id>3455</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table15" msdata:rowOrder="14">
        <id>3473</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table16" msdata:rowOrder="15">
        <id>3476</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table17" msdata:rowOrder="16">
        <id>3496</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table18" msdata:rowOrder="17">
        <id>3518</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table19" msdata:rowOrder="18">
        <id>3520</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table20" msdata:rowOrder="19">
        <id>3549</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table21" msdata:rowOrder="20">
        <id>3570</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table22" msdata:rowOrder="21">
        <id>3571</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table23" msdata:rowOrder="22">
        <id>3573</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table24" msdata:rowOrder="23">
        <id>3582</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table25" msdata:rowOrder="24">
        <id>3589</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table26" msdata:rowOrder="25">
        <id>3607</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table27" msdata:rowOrder="26">
        <id>3609</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table28" msdata:rowOrder="27">
        <id>3610</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table29" msdata:rowOrder="28">
        <id>3616</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table30" msdata:rowOrder="29">
        <id>3618</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table31" msdata:rowOrder="30">
        <id>3630</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table32" msdata:rowOrder="31">
        <id>3632</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table33" msdata:rowOrder="32">
        <id>3633</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table34" msdata:rowOrder="33">
        <id>3801</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table35" msdata:rowOrder="34">
        <id>3802</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table36" msdata:rowOrder="35">
        <id>3803</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table37" msdata:rowOrder="36">
        <id>3804</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table38" msdata:rowOrder="37">
        <id>3810</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table39" msdata:rowOrder="38">
        <id>3815</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table40" msdata:rowOrder="39">
        <id>3816</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table41" msdata:rowOrder="40">
        <id>3817</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table42" msdata:rowOrder="41">
        <id>3822</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table43" msdata:rowOrder="42">
        <id>3823</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table44" msdata:rowOrder="43">
        <id>3824</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table45" msdata:rowOrder="44">
        <id>3825</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table46" msdata:rowOrder="45">
        <id>3826</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table47" msdata:rowOrder="46">
        <id>3827</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table48" msdata:rowOrder="47">
        <id>3828</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table49" msdata:rowOrder="48">
        <id>3829</id>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table50" msdata:rowOrder="49">
        <id>3830</id>
      </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

**ExportXML** generated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<string>&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;2&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3133&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3134&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3135&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3157&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3183&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3263&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3291&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3292&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3371&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3429&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3431&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3439&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3455&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3473&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3476&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3496&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3518&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3520&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3549&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3570&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3571&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3573&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3582&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3589&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3607&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3609&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3610&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3616&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3618&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3630&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3632&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3633&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3801&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3802&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3803&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3804&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3810&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3815&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3816&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3817&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3822&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3823&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3824&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3825&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3826&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3827&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3828&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3829&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;id&gt;3830&lt;/id&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
&lt;/NewDataSet&gt;</string>
```

Comment: What exactly issue is ..

Comment: @sandeeprawat Can't load data from either of the XML's I mentioned

Comment: I doubt that file are correct i feel "<?xml version="1.0"?>" and standerd xml for missing...

Comment: I've updated it with the exact XML file outputs from SSIS

Comment: what is the error ...

Comment: indicated in the question. None of the 2 Methods seem to load the data for different reasons.

Comment: @AS91, does the web service actually write out the xml into files, or is there a step that generates them? If there is that step, it might be better to serialize them into a C# script task, then shred the XML into the database.

Comment: When I invoke the web service online based on the Method (ExportDataset or ExportXML), I get the respective outputs. If I use the SSIS Web Service Task and then select the Method(again ExportDataset or ExportXML) in the 'Input' section and 'Output' it to an XML file, the web service dumps the respective outputs into that file, the code for which you can see above. I'm not sure if either of them are usable XML codes which can be fed into an "XML Source" task coz of the problems I'm facing as I stated in question